# jar file doesn't showing perfect design as run from NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have designed as my choice. but this design is showing perfect when I run my project from the NetBeans IDE.

But when I build and clean it to make jar file and run it, it doesn't show the perfect design as run from NetBeans. It's getting bigger all the components and get out from the display. Here the following two images:

- The first one is run from the NetBeans IDE.
- The second one is run as jar file.

**Run from NetBeans IDE:**

[image: NetBeansIDE]

**Run as jar file:**
[image: JarFileRun]

Comment: Is the environment where you are running the jar and the environment created by NetBeans the same? (i.e. same version of Java, etc.)

Comment: Even if you address this problem, you will still face the possibility of different font metrics when your application runs on other computers.  Are you hard coding font sizes?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Wonderful helped  me. I have 3 environment installed.i just uninstalled two unnecessary  environment and run the jar file and it works  perfectly .thank you very much 'Leftist Tachyon' thank you 'VGR' and thanks 'Andre Thompson'.

Comment: Tip: Add @LeftistTachyon (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. As an aside 1) I thought VGR gave much better advice, since you cannot rely on any particular environment and should aim to make code work on any. 2) Only one person can be notified per comment, so you'll need to tag VGR if you want to gain their attention.

Comment: Actually I'm new to stack. and I don’t know as far.  But thanks to you @AndreThompson for your special advice that, how i can notify them.

Comment: @LeftistTachyon Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @VGR thnaks to you for your special comment.